# Malformed SQL Statement: Expected token 'USING' but found Identifier with value 't' instead

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am trying to merge to a SQL Database using the following code in Databricks with pyspark

```
query = """
    MERGE INTO deltadf t
    USING df s
    ON s.SLAId_Id = t.SLAId_Id
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET *
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *
  """
driver_manager = spark._sc._gateway.jvm.java.sql.DriverManager
con = driver_manager.getConnection(url) #
stmt = con.createStatement()
stmt.executeUpdate(query)
stmt.close()
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
SQLException: Malformed SQL Statement: Expected token 'USING' but found Identifier with value 't' instead at position 25.
```

Any thoughts on where  might be going wrong?

Comment: What database are you connecting to?

Comment: Hi ScootCork, thanks for reaching out. I am connecting to sql database

Comment: That is to say, a MS SQL database

Comment: I'm also getting the same error when I try to use the same code to merge with Dynamics 365 Account table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you're getting this exact error. However I believe there are a number of issues with what you are trying to do.

Running the query via JDBC makes it run in SQL Server only. Construct like `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET *` / `WHEN NOT MATCHED INSERT *` will not work. Databricks accepts it, but for SQL Server you need to explicitly provide columns to update and values to insert ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)).

Also, do you actually have tables named `deltadf` and `df` in SQL Server? I suppose you have a Dataframe or temporary view named `df`... this will not work. As said, this query executes in SQL Server only. If you want to upload data from Dataframe use `df.write.format("jdbc").save` ([reference](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html)).

See [this Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d666bae6a886d86a0410bc79b87695ab) - if `deltadf` and `df` are tables, running this query in SQL Server (any version) will only complain about `Incorrect syntax near '*'`.

Answer (score 1):

> **SQLException: Malformed SQL Statement: Expected token 'USING' but found Identifier with value 't' instead at position 25.**

if you missed updating any specific field or specific syntax, you will get this error.

I performed [merge operation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5oM2bUyH0o) its working fine for me without error, Please follow below reference .

[image: Ref1]
[image: Ref3]
[image: ref4]

**Reference:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5oM2bUyH0o

https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-update.html#upsert-into-a-table-using-merge

https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-merge-statement-overview-and-examples/

Comment: Isn't there the posibility to update all with the following ```WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET *
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *```